# Different behaviour between stackblitz and local project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, hammer.js, stackblitz

Hello everyone thanks for your read.

My project is on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-m8xt8c?file=package.json

Very simple, just a press button that increases button progress number.

The problem is that I have the same project on my desktop and I launch it with ionic serve, but nothing work well.
I press the button and my button progress number doesn't increase..

Hammer is correctly installed :
console request : window.Hammer

response :

```
ƒ Hammer(element, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.recognizers = ifUndefined(options.recognizers, Hammer.defaults.preset);
    return new Manager(element, options);
}
```

Anyone has an idea? A solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: does the console present any errors ?

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: No error, no warning